# How to properly add an internal SATA drive to Ubuntu 20.04 desktop?

Tags: hard-drive

I have added a SanDisk SSD SATA 1 TB disk to my Ubuntu machine.
I can see it being recognized in the BIOS, but my attempts to get the kernal to recogbnize it and allocate an /dev/sd* entry to it via either a scan or reboot do not yield the desired result.
Here is  the listing in /dev:

```
 ls /dev/s*
/dev/sda  /dev/sg0  /dev/snapshot  /dev/stderr  /dev/stdin  /dev/stdout

/dev/shm:

/dev/snd:
by-path    hwC0D0  pcmC0D0c  pcmC0D10p  pcmC0D3p  pcmC0D8p  seq
controlC0  hwC0D2  pcmC0D0p  pcmC0D2c   pcmC0D7p  pcmC0D9p  timer
```

Is there a method by which I can get the kernel to recognize this device?

Comment: The question is very unclear.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395325/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Thank you @user535733 ! After running partd -l I realized that /dev/sda  IS in fact tha device I was looking for. The original boot device have been assigned /dev/nvme0n1. I can accept your comment as the answer

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question. I merely offered the first diagnostic step.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user535733 I ran parted -l. This revealed that My original boot device have been assigned  /dev/nvme0n1 and the kernel has appropriately created /dev/sda for my new device.

Comment: Best to partition it with gpt. What partitions you create may depend on how you plan to use it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: NVMe drives are always identified as such;  /dev/nvme0n1 is NOT a new thing that happens because you added a new drive, it was always like that.